# cookie session does not stored on nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I have been working on MERN stack application, I tried to create login module for my application , so that i have used google authentication in the server side using passportjs. Every thing working good when i use localhost,but when my app running on aws server then  nodejs does not store my cookie session,so that passport deserializeUser does not working, and passport serializeUser working good.
*my react app running on digital ocean server.
*my node app running on aws server.

API call in my react app:

```
axios.get(url,{withCredentials: true}).then((response) =>{
console.log('login:',response.data)
}).catch((e)=>{
console.log('error:',e)
 })
}
```

session setting in my node app:

```
router.use(cookieParser());

router.use( session( { secret: 'keyboard cat',
cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
resave: true, 
saveUninitialized: false
}
)
);
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
```

Cookie session and passport session are stored and working fine when the app in  running my local host.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the Same Origin Policy of browser? Does your client web page uses a **different** domain from your API server

Comment: Hii jess, Thank  you for your reply. Yes, my client web page uses different domain,  Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with google authentication. Is it using `cookie` based session management? Maybe you can check the `domain` of the session related cookies in your browser

Comment: Yes it is used cookies besed on session  management.